# Which insulating tape and when?

Tags: pcb, heatsink, laptop, insulation, motherboard

There are quite a few tapes out there, from the plain black electrical tape to different color variations to Scotch 33+, 77, 88 to Kaptons (polyamide), I have also seen some velcro type wraps which probably are not velcro. I just learned these are fleece electrical tapes, so these join in the comparison. I have heard negatives for both, that electrical tape gunks or that kapton is easily pierced, but then there are thicknesses. Anyways it seems like it comes down to the type of application so which is used when (and also why)?

To give a more complex at least for me, example; I have a laptop which I am installing a heatsink, the heatsink model is for the same laptop, but for a model with a dGPU which I do not have, I have the non dGPU model. So everything fits perfectly well at least to some point that is as in addition there is a naked heatsink part hovering over and very close to the motherboard where an actual GPU die should be. What would be the best way to insulate it, put a Kapton on the heatsink, or on both the heatsink and the PCB, but wouldn't also a Scotch 33 (or even something worse, although I would like to not risk it in this situation) be sufficient as temperatures are not that high, then again I see tons more polyamide tapes on PCBs and they sure do not get as hot as a heatsink. In terms of what sticks to a metal surface better I do not know.

Comment: google `fleece electrical tape`

Comment: @jsotola Huh, so I did really see such tape, iirc in a heatsink, too. Why would it be used over the above? I will include this ine in the question.

Comment: They even have liquid rubber for wire bonds..Use Kapton for high temp as polyamide is best but not flexible yet thin.  It all depends on App. Polyester is better than PVC but more expensive. PVC is colourful and adequate for some indoor use but gets brittle and loses stiction with environmental stress

Comment: Nylon is (aliphatic) polyamide. Kapton is poly**i**mide.

Answer (score 0):

in your application I'de use kapton on the heatsink and then a space-filling glue betetween the taped heatsink and the board: eg. silicone, epoxy, or hot-melt.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I could very well use only a non-conductive thermal pad in-between (which I think it will not be affecting thermals) between to prevent damage too, but both would be even better I guess. Why Kapton over polymide and fleece, is it because of higher temperatures?